# What are the limits for European banks to allow crypto trading?

Tags: transactions, trading, trade, europe

What became clear last couple of years, is that European banks want to restrict crypto trading. Here are some examples:

1. [Santander UK started to block sending money to exchanges completely](https://www.reuters.com/business/finance/santander-block-uk-transfers-crypto-exchanges-2023-2022-11-04/).
2. [Belgian banks block receiving money on IBAN coming from selling crypto](https://www.hln.be/economie/banken-blokkeren-toestroom-cryptowinsten-uit-angst-voor-torenhoge-boetes%7Ea7613149/)
3. [A Dutch bank blocked crypto transactions that are approved by an accountant](https://www.quotenet.nl/nieuws/a213156/ing-blokkeert-rekening-na-crypotransactie-ondernemer-start-proces-om-bij-rekening-te-kunnen-213156/)
4. [Another Dutch bank considers crypto transactions as unethical](https://tweakers.net/nieuws/92881/interne-commissie-rabobank-niet-meewerken-aan-bitcoin-handel.html)
5. [Bank of Spain warns for blocking crypto sales](https://es.cointelegraph.com/news/bank-of-spain-warns-your-bank-can-block-you-from-buying-cryptocurrencies)

So what are the right European  banks to have an account to do crypto trading? And what are their limits to allow transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link that has a list of various banks in Europe that are fine with crypto trading:

https://thebanks.eu/articles/crypto-friendly-banks-in-Europe

Most definitely DYOR, I'm not sure how trustworthy these banks are.

Speaking of trust, it seems to me that those five articles you linked show pretty clearly that major European banks are willing to and can easily control what you do with "your" money.

A trust-minimized solution would be buying bitcoin off of a decentralized exchange such as Bisq and using your own Bitcoin node for sending and receiving your coins. Just my two sats :)

Comment: Thanks Marco. This is comes close to what I need. Is thebanks.eu reliable? Who´s funding it?

Comment: Do you have an idea of limits? What amounts do they block?